# Select KML feature with specific attribute

Tags: openlayers-2, kml, fields-attributes

Im using Openlayers, and importing polygon data to the map with KML files.

How could i select the feature which has the attribute name="TEST" ?

KML def:

```
<Placemark>
<Name>TEST</Name>
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>//Some coordinates\\</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
</Placemark>
```

Iknow that you can loop trough them to check it. But i was hoping for something more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenLayers doesn't provide convenient method for getting features by custom attribute. You can see my implementation of getFeaturesBy method, [example](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/commit/1d95b215cccfaa064e1cc01b7dc149d5af80460a).

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to my problem using the `preFeatureInsert` method. :)